# Split string of 2 words in separate words [but sometimes there is only word in the string...]

Tags: regex, string, split

I have strings like "`AMS.I-I.D. ver.5`" and "`AM0011 ver. 2`", of which the "`ver. *`" needs to be stripped. 
I have done that with: `(^A.*)(ver.\s\d{1,2})`

The problem occurs when there is no version number like "`AM0003`". 
How can I make the `(ver.\s\d{1,2})` part optional?

Answer (score 6):

The reason why it's not working when you add a question mark is because your first group is matching [greedily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy). Try changing it to a non-greedy match and then making the second group optional:

```
^(A.*?)(ver\.\s\d{1,2})?$
     ^                 ^
 non-greedy        optional
```

Note that in both parts the only change is the addition of a question mark but the question mark has a different meaning in each case.

Also, in one of your examples there is no whitespace between the text `ver.` and the version number so you should consider making the whitespace optional in your regular expression.

See the regular expression in action on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/2TcqnqDmnW).

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: +1 Yes, I didn't spot that error in the original regular expression. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

To have an optionnal capture with regex you just have to use the `?` operator.

```
(^A.*)(ver\.\s\d{1,2})?
```

---

**Resources :**

- [regular-expressions.info - Optional items](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since the examples show a space between the two words (the product ID and the version information), I would expect to design a regex which uses that space to separate the parts.  In Perl:

```
$line =~ s/^(A\S+)\s+ver\.\s?\d{1,2}/$1/;
```

This removes (without capturing) the version; if the version is not present, then the substitution does nothing.

```
$line =~ s/^(A\S+)(?:\s+(ver\.\s?\d{1,2}))?/$1/;
```

This is an almost trivial variation on the idea; it captures the version string if present (as well as substituting, etc.  Note the subtlety that the space before the version string is included in the optional material but not captured '`(?:...)?`', but the version information is captured without leading spaces.

Quoting the regexes in the abstract, without tying them to the Perl context (though they're still using PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expression - notation), you could write:

```
^(A\S+)(?:\s+(ver\.\s?\d{1,2}))?
```